# jQuery: Gallerific Half Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get the jQuery gallerific plugin working at http://justrecip.es/ViewRecipes.aspx?recipeid=S9ML32WQO3&act=view . The gallery is loaded correctly, but neither the thumb grid nor the navigation (next/previous image)  buttons work. There are no script errors, but it seems this is  a JavaScript problem of some sort.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div class="gallery-content">
    <!-- Move controls above slideshow -->
    <div id="controls" class="controls"></div> 
    <div class="slideshow-container">


        <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
        <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="caption" class="caption-container">
        <div class="photo-index"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/wVCP5/)

Comment: Thanks, positioning the controls outside the container fixed the problem.